How to preserve the original "Created By" and "Modified By" information when restoring files from SharePoint to Azure in a .NET application?
I have a .NET application that is used to back up files from a SharePoint document library to Azure. During the restoration process, the "Created By" and "Modified By" fields are being populated as the SharePoint App , but I need these fields to reflect the actual user who created or last modified the file in SharePoint.
How can I retain the original "Created By" and "Modified By" information when restoring files from Azure to SharePoint or during the backup process?
I've checked the SharePoint API documentation and Microsoft Graph documentation, but it seems these fields are managed automatically.
Has anyone successfully modified these fields or found a workaround? Any pointers or examples would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
